# jquery load not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax

web page : http://sideradesign.com/eco-art/gallery/

This code works fine in all brwosers except IE8 (haven't tested IE6/7)

```
jQuery(function () {
  jQuery("#main-content").append("<img src='../images/ajax-loader.gif' id='ajax-loader' />");
  $ajaxSpinner = jQuery("#ajax-loader");
  var thisTarget = jQuery('#thumbnail-nav ul li:eq(0) a.thumb').attr('href');
  jQuery('#main-content').load(thisTarget + " .entry-content");
  jQuery('a.thumb').click(function () {
    $ajaxSpinner.fadeIn();
    jQuery('#main-content').animate({
        opacity: "0.1"
    });
    thisTarget = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#main-content').load(thisTarget + " .entry-content", function () {
        $ajaxSpinner.fadeOut();
        jQuery('#main-content').animate({
            opacity: "1"
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: What happens in IE?  Anything?  Does the HTTP request get made?  Are there errors?

Comment: There is a lot going on that isn't related to load. Try breaking it down into pieces until you have the shortest code that still has the problem. http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: hi pointy, thanks for replying.
in IE, the content that is supposed to be loaded simply doesn't appear. Nor on page load, nor when I click a link.
you can try it for yourself : http://sideradesign.com/eco-art/gallery/, try clicking on a thumbnail

Comment: I trimmed down the code but it still doesn't display the content

Comment: This is pretty weird. Stepping through it in the IE8 debugger, it's getting into the "click" handler, and it's got the right URL, and there aren't any errors inside the jQuery code.  If it were me, I'd try this with the uncompressed version of jQuery so that I could step through that code more easily. (Also, I'd upgrade to 1.4.2.)

Comment: I've upgraded to jquery 1.4.2 uncompressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the CSS that's causing the problem. I disabled the stylesheet and I can see the content appearing.
this is resolved

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support the opacity property in CSS, so animating it from jquery isn't going to work. Instead you could use [fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/), which works around this problem.

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with it, for a couple of reasons. The "load" doesn't seem to be happening at all.

Comment: I just ran the debugger in IE8, and the callback function is being called.